# Cache Storage to store temporary Values-Android

Tags: android, caching, storage

I want my app to store few values and that values has to be used all through the app and has to be destroyed when the app is closed. I tried sending values through intending but it can send values to the particular activity. So Is there a way to store data in the cache so that it can be used when the app is running and will be destroyed when it is closed.

Answer (score -2):

yes,

## 1.You can define a variable in Application class.

and wherever in the application you need that value,
you can access it from

```
((YourAppClass) getApplication()).variable ;
```

## 2.You also can use Static variable in particular class like

```
class Deta{
    public static int value;
}
```

and can access from anywhere in the application like

```
Data.value = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks For the Answer, @RBK. But Is there any other way to get data into Cache Storage.

Comment: no, can not store a variable in Cache. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html